# How to Access ASP.NET Page Controls During PreInit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, preinit

Recently I've used a class as explained [here](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/12/20/accessing-aspnet-page-controls-during-preinit/) to access dynamic controls during PreInit. The post is titled as "Accessing ASP.NET Page Controls During PreInit", and in local it works perfect, but on server I get the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1031: Type expected

Source Error:

Line 12:     /// in turn makes our controls accessible so that we can make the calls below. 
Line 13:     /// </remarks> 
Line 14:     public static void PrepareChildControlsDuringPreInit(this Page page)
Line 15:     {
Line 16:         // Walk up the master page chain and tickle the getter on each one
```

I'd appreciate highly if someone give me a solution or an advise on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like, locally, you are running on a newer version of the .NET Framework than your server.

Extension methods are only supported (with the syntax you're using) in .NET 3.5 and later, I believe.  So if you are running a lower version of the .NET Framework than that on your server, I think that would cause the compiler error you're getting (when it tries to compile on the server).

Comment: hi :) thanks for your answer. The versions are the same. Is there any other solution?

Comment: both are 3.5, although server supports 4.5 too.

Comment: I removed the "targetFramework="4.5" from <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"> and got the same error in local. What should I do?

Comment: I found these 4.0s in my web.config:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages enableViewState="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">

Comment: @Kardo So you are targeting 4.5 on your local site. What are you targeting on the server?

Comment: @Kardo Is that second snippet from your server's config file (the one with 4.0 in it)?  I find it odd that you're adding the WindowsForms assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your advise :) I downgraded the local and did some changes and settings then uploaded the changes, and now both work (local and server). But I didn't get your point by saying: (I find it odd that you're adding the WindowsForms assembly). Please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @Kardo Great work!  I'm glad I could help.  You can disregard my comment about WindowsForms.  I just noticed "`<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms,`" in the snippet you put in the comments, and thought that seemed odd (since you're using ASP.NET - web forms - not Windows Forms).  It's not a critical thing, but you can look through your code files and make sure you're not "`using System.Windows.Forms`" at the top of any of them.